# How to define format in Java String.format(format,args..) where args are dynamic

Tags: java

When the args are dynamic how to define the format,where args are 1 we can define the format like “sss %d”?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you provide an example? Some code?

Answer (score 0):

Official javadoc (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) states three kinds of formatting types:

- General, character and number : `%[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion`
- Dates: `%[argument_index$][flags][width]conversion`
- Others: `%[flags][width]conversion`

None of them allows you to use conditions to represent it in case of non matching with `args ...`.

I think you could parse previously both parameters: `String` format and `Object[]` arguments, to create a coherent pair of parameters depending on your runtime circumstances.